# Trouble Automatically Restoring Nuget Packages Xunit and Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: visual-studio, json.net, nuget, nuget-package, xunit.net

I'm working on performing a nuget migration to create a common package directory across all solutions. I wrote a script to get rid of NuGet config files, target files, hint paths (this should not be needed with NuGet automatic package restore), and a couple of other things in the project and solution files. I now have one NuGet config file.

The migration worked as expected for the most part. However I ran into issues with Xunit and Newtonsoft.Json packages. For example, some projects could not find the Xunit package and Visual Studio showed the following error: "the type or namespace 'Xunit' could not be found (are you missing an assembly reference?" The only way I was able to fix this was to reinstall the Xunit package by running the following command:

```
Update-Package –reinstall xunit
```

when I reinstalled the Xunit hint paths were added back in the project files and the following code was added to the app.config file:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"   culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

My question is why do I seem to need the hint paths and some of this other stuff only for the xunit and Newtonsoft.json packages? Is there a way to fix this without them? This is the exact sort of thing I'm trying to avoid by performing this migration.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a packages.config file then you need the hint paths so MSBuild can resolve assemblies. xunit and JSON.NET are not installed into the GAC so without the hint paths, or some other mechanism such as a reference path configured for the project, the build cannot find the assemblies. Also any time you update the NuGet packages the hint paths will be added back to the project file.

A similar problem will occur for any custom MSBuild .targets files that are used. If you remove them from the project then MSBuild cannot find them.

NuGet restore will only download the packages and extract them into the packages directory. It will not modify the project files.

If you want to avoid using hint paths then you should look at using a project.json file instead of a packages.config file. If you use a project.json file then the assemblies are resolved at build time using a NuGet targets file without having to have the references or hint paths in your project file (.csproj).